# EditButton bug with StackNavigationViewStyle

Tags: swiftui

when use StackNavigationViewStyle, EditButton doesn't work

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in
                ....
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteBooks)
        }
        ...
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: ...)
        ....
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}
```

[image: No delete or edit options shown in edit mode]

Comment: What does 'EditButton doesn't work' mean?  How does it not work?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I ran on Xcode 12.5 (12E262), iPhone 12 running iOS 14.5 and it worked fine.

Comment: tap editButton, editButton show 'Done', but table view no change, table view  should show delete button @ElTomato

Comment: Where does a guy named 'deleteBooks' come from?

Comment: show us the code for `deleteBooks`

Comment: I'm seeing this too. The OP's screen shot shows that the edit button was pushed but the delete button is missing (red circle minus). This only happens if the user selects edit before selecting any item's details.  It doesn't happen if the DefaultNavigationViewStyle is chosen, but that style is ugly. This should be reported to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Press edit button first:

import SwiftUI

struct Order: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var orders = [Order(), Order(), Order()]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(orders) { order in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(order: order, orders: $orders)) {
                        Text(order.id.uuidString)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    orders.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems( leading: EditButton())
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    let order: Order
    @Binding var orders: [Order]

    var body: some View {
        if orders.contains(order) {
            Text(order.id.uuidString)
        } else {
            Text("No selection")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a complete example and even reproduces the problem in SwiftUI preview. I have not been able to work around this, so I plan to submit a bug report to Apple.

Comment: You need Xcode 12 to see the error.  I just tried Xcode 13 beta 5 and they changed it so that StackNavigationViewStyle is now the same as DefaultNavigationViewStyle. The Default style does not make the list items extend to the left/right sides. I'm not happy with that UI change, but it does fix the problem.

Comment: Because of the way Apple decided to fix the problem in Xcode 13, my solution was to remove the line mentioning the StackNavigationViewStyle and just let the list have that extra border that the DefaultNavigationViewStyle has. On iPad landscape you get the double column view style for "free."